# pyopencl import error cffi.so undefined symbol

Tags: pyopencl

I successfully installed the pyopencl but I am getting an import error. I am stuck here and unable to progress further. Any help would be much appreciated

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-1f241b2ad48f> in <module>()

      5 from __future__ import division

      6 import numpy as np

----> 7 import pyopencl
 
      8 import pyopencl.array

      9 import math, time 

/home/highschool/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyopencl-2016.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pyopencl/__init__.py in <module>()
     32 

     33 try: 

---> 34     import pyopencl.cffi_cl as _cl

     35 except ImportError:

     36     import os

/home/highschool/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyopencl-2016.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pyopencl/cffi_cl.py in <module>()

     37 from pytools import memoize_method

     38 

---> 39 from pyopencl._cffi import ffi as _ffi

     40 from .compyte.array import f_contiguous_strides, c_contiguous_strides

     41 

ImportError: /home/highschool/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyopencl-2016.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pyopencl/_cffi.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVNSt7__cxx1115basic_stringbufIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the the [dual ABI](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html)  in `libstdc++` with gcc5.1 for `std::string` and `std::list`.  Anaconda now installs `libstdc++.so.6.0.19` (presumably because they've added a Python package with a C++ library) [from gcc 4.8.3 and pre dual ABI](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html) where as Ubuntu 16.04 comes with gcc 5.4 and `libstdc++.6.0.21`. When you build pyopencl it builds and links against your system `libstdc++` but when you  try to import `pyopencl` it dynamically links against the Anaconda one and fails to find the symbols.

It should be possible to solve this by adding `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` to the `CXXFLAGS` list in the pyopencl `siteconf.py`. That solves the `std::string` issue but has other missing symbols:

```
ImportError: /home/cryan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyopencl-2016.2.1-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/pyopencl/_cffi.abi3.so: undefined symbol: _ZNSt6thread15_M_start_threadESt10shared_ptrINS_10_Impl_baseEEPFvvE
```

Your options are:

1. Install gcc from Anaconda (`conda install gcc`) and build pyopencl using that. Unfortunately if you have Anaconda on your `PATH` you'll use their gcc everywhere.
2. Just delete/rename the `libstdc++` in `~/anaconda3/lib`: `cd ~/anaconda3/lib; mv libstdc++.so libstdc++.annoying; mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.annoying.6`. Python modules will find your system one which should be backwards compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the *exact* same issue.

```
ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f1779268ba42> in <module>()
----> 1 import pyopencl as cl

/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyopencl/__init__.py in <module>()
     32 
     33 try:
---> 34     import pyopencl.cffi_cl as _cl
     35 except ImportError:
     36     import os

/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyopencl/cffi_cl.py in <module>()
     37 from pytools import memoize_method
     38 
---> 39 from pyopencl._cffi import ffi as _ffi
     40 from .compyte.array import f_contiguous_strides, c_contiguous_strides
     41 

ImportError: /opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyopencl/_cffi.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVNSt7__cxx1115basic_stringbufIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
```

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, using the libOpenCL.so in AMDAPPSDK-3.0. I am able to run some of the OpenCL examples included with this SDK, so I believe this is a pyopencl issue.

Comment: I am also using ubuntu 16.04, I was able to install it in 14,04. I reinstalled pyopencl but no luck.