# pyopencl Import Error

Tags: python, dll, opencl, pyopencl

I'm on Windows 10 running python 3.5.4 through Anaconda with pyopencl                  2017.2 from conda-forge, installed through Anaconda. My system is an i5 4670K with an R9 290 running driver version
17.11.1 with OpenCL Version
23.20.788.0.

When trying to import the pyopencl module I experience the following error

```
    >>> import pyopencl as cl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "[my home folder]\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyopencl\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    import pyopencl.cffi_cl as _cl
  File "[my home folder]\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyopencl\cffi_cl.py", line 39, in <module>
    from pyopencl._cffi import ffi as _ffi
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

The error appears to occur when loading `_cffi.pyd`. This error has similarities with problems shown in previous threads:

[Python pyopencl Import Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43077427/python-pyopencl-import-error?rq=1)

[cffi load failure when trying to import PyOpenCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45527726/cffi-load-failure-when-trying-to-import-pyopencl)

[pyopencl import error cffi.so undefined symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41096313/pyopencl-import-error-cffi-so-undefined-symbol?rq=1)

However, in spite of the installation completing (seemingly) without error, me installing the OCL SDK:s from both AMD and Intel the problem persists. I also updated my grahics card drivers.

I tried using Dependency Walker to check dependencies of `_cffi.pyd`, as described in the following thread:

[Python pyopencl DLL load failed even with latest drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491911/python-pyopencl-dll-load-failed-even-with-latest-drivers)

This did turn up a lot of circular dependencies and missing dependencies under `opencl.dll` with names beginning in `API-MS-WIN` and `EXT-MS-WIN`. The dependency errors persisted when renaming the `opencl.dll` in `/System32` and using the one in `\Anaconda3\Library\bin` instead.

Doing a bit of searching I found this thread:

[Dependency Walker: missing dlls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36240215/dependency-walker-missing-dlls)

which basically says the missing dependencies are nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 3):

I was also having this problem and my research led me to this document that helped install a compatible version: https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/mot/master/mot.pdf

The error is because you do not have a compatible version of pyopencl and opencl driver for AMD or Intel.

Quote:

> Installing a precompiled binary wheel (.whl) is the easiest way to
>   install PyOpenCL, but only works if the wheel is compiled for your
>   specific Python implementation. At Christoph Gohlke website
>   (http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyopencl) you can find a
>   range of PyOpenCL binary packages. If there is a compatible one for
>   your system, download that version. You can see if it is compatible if
>   the Python version and OpenCl version in the binary name matches that
>   of your installed Python and driver supported versions. Note that many
>   drivers, such as nVIDIA’s only support OpenCL 1.2, so in that case
>   take the wheel with “+cl12” in the name, and not e.g. “+cl21”. For
>   example if you have 64-bit Windows system with Python 3.5 and your GPU
>   or CPU drivers support OpenCL 1.2 you need to download the wheel with
>   “+cl12”, `win-amd64` and cp35m in the name (note the format,
>   cp<version>m, the m is important). (To check which Python version you
>   have you can run `python --version` in the command line).

This should help you

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue on my Intel HD Graphics 4400 GPU. It worked before (I can't remember exactly how I got it to work earlier). At some point I got the exact same pyopencl import error as Asker described.

After some trying I installed the Intel OpenCL driver from here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers. During installation it showed that my regular Intel HD 4400 driver needed to be uninstalled first, which the installation tool did for me. Then the OpenCL driver got installed, and I could use OpenCL on my GPU again. 
My theory: probably, my setup got corrupted during a Windows update which sometimes tends to update device drivers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Download the `opencl.dll` file from google.

Go to the location where the `pyopencl` library is installed, specifically where the `tools.py` is, and paste the **DLL** file there.

This fixed the error for me.